# Application pool identity account giving login error for sharepoint search page

Tags: 2007, error, iis, sql, application-pool

I am getting a "Login failed for user " error when try to search on my SharePoint site. The site is loading fine, but its the search page thats throwing the error.

### Event viewer info

Process information: 
    Process ID: 3644 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: "Application Pool Identity Account"

Exception information: 
    Exception type: SqlException 
    Exception message: Login failed for user "Application Pool Identity Account"

Comment: Can you try to manually give permission that account to SharePoint search database in SQL Server?

Comment: I have checked the access to Search Database in SQL, the user is having proper rights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a web part (on that particular page) which had a connection string with SQL. The connection string (sql instance) was wrong. Correcting the instance resolved the issue.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Application Pool Identity doesn't have access to the Search database in SQL Server.  Check the permissions and if necessary, grant it the correct rights.

[This TechNet forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/ca7d53d8-88e2-4a82-9978-8695a7074e5d/application-pool-identity-does-not-have-access-to-profiled) has a little more information that you might find helpful.  The article is about the profile database but you might find a little more information about your error.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have checked the access to Search Database in SQL, the user is having proper rights.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try giving proper rights to all 4 Search Databases in your Search service.Search service uses 4 databases namely Administration,Analytics Reporting,Crawl Store and Links Store, you can find these each individual database names in Search Service Application in Central Admin.